# Filter on date in r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I am attempting to limit my dataframe to the days of each month between the 20th and the 25th . I got a big dataset with many dates ranging over many years. It looks something like this:

```
Event          Date
Football       20.12.2016
Work           15.10.2019
Holiday        30.11.2018
Running        24.01.2020
```

I would then like to restrict my results to:

```
Event          Date
Football       20.12.2016
Running        24.01.2020
```

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution using `dplyr`/`lubridate` although I have converted your `Date` column using `as.Date`

```
 df <-
      data.frame(
        Event = c("Football", "Work", "Holiday", "Running"),
        Date = c("20.12.2016", "15.10.2019", "30.11.2018", "24.01.2020")
      )

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

df %>% filter(day(Date) >= 20 & day(Date) <= 25)
```

Output

```
1 Football 2016-12-20
2  Running 2020-01-24
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a literal string-match, keeping your `Date` column as strings (not real dates):

```r
# base R
subset(quux, between(as.integer(sub("\\..*", "", Date)), 20, 25))
#      Event       Date
# 1 Football 20.12.2016
# 4  Running 24.01.2020

# dplyr
quux %>% 
  filter(between(as.integer(sub("\\..*", "", Date)), 20, 25))
```

`between` can be from `dplyr::`, `data.table::`, or we can easily craft our own with:

```r
between <- function(x, y, z) y <= x & x <= z
```

... though the two package versions are more robust to `NA`s and other issues.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Event = c("Football", "Work", "Holiday", "Running"), Date = c("20.12.2016", "15.10.2019", "30.11.2018", "24.01.2020")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```